# Java JPA - OneToOne Relation between Entities not working

Tags: java, jpa, entity, nullpointerexception, one-to-one

**Licitatie Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="licitatie")
public class Licitatie implements Serializable {
    ...

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Licitatie
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="licitatie")
    private Produs produs;

    ...
}
```

**Produs Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produs")
//@DiscriminatorColumn(name="id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@MappedSuperclass
public class Produs implements Serializable {
    ...

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Produs
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="licitatie_id")
    private Licitatie licitatie;

    ...
}
```

Database:

Licitatie:

```
id  start   status
1   5   open
2   5   open
3   5   open
```

Produs:

```
id  licitatie_id    DTYPE   description
1   1           Carte   ...
2   2           Carte   ...
3   3           Carte   ...
```

After I run tris query: **"SELECT t FROM Licitatie t"**, the attribute Product from object of type Licitatie is null. But there are records in tables.

What I'm doing wrong?

* EDIT ***

After I get data from table, calling getProdus() return this message:

**{IndirectSet: not instantiated}**

Comment: You might want to take a look at Embeddable annotation...

Comment: I see nothing wrong except the MappedSuperClass annotation. Are you sure **every** licitatie has its own produs (because the query returns every licitatie from the database)? Is there a unique constraint on the licitatie_id column? What's the JPA engine?

Comment: I am sure that every "licitatie" has only one "produs" record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I've added column PRODUS_ID to licitatie table.

Licitatie: id produs_id ...
Produs: id, licitatie_id ...